# Use the list of sequence & write a program that finds the sequence with the highest GC content

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I need to write a program to calculate the GC content of each item in list and  print percent content and sequence with highest.

I have tried using a for statement and trying to combine the counts and divide by the total in each sequence

Use the list of sequence `["ATATCCG", "TCCG", "ATGTACTG", "ATGGCTG", "ATCA"]` as an example, write a program that finds the sequence with the highest GC content (the percentage of G and C nucleotides) among a list of sequences. The program should print the sequence and its GC content.

Tried Below but did not give correct answers

```
dnas = ["ATATCCG", "TCCG", "ATGTACTG", "ATGGCTG", "ATCA"]

def gc_percentage(dna):
    count = 0
    for sequence in dna:
        if sequence in "GC":
            count += 1
    return (count * 100) / len(dnas)


maxgc = 0
for i in range(len(dnas)):
    if gc_percentage(dnas[i]) > gc_percentage(dnas[maxgc]):
        max_gc = i

print(dnas[max_gc])
print(str(gc_percentage(data[max_gc])))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to sum the occurrences of G and C as a discriminator you can do

```
print(
    max(
        ((s.count('G')+s.count('C'), s) for s in dnas)
    )
)
```

It prints the tuple with highest GC count (count first, then sequence), in your case

```
(4, "ATGGCTG")
```